# ParseLambda method throws an exception

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I am trying to use ParseLambda method available in System.Linq.Dynamic library. When I execute the following simple example,

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace DynamicLINQDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
            ParameterExpression y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "y");
            LambdaExpression e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new ParameterExpression[] { x, y }, null, "(x + y) * 2");
        }
    }
}
```

it throws the following exception.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser' threw an exception.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core, this works:

```cs
ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
ParameterExpression y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "y");
LambdaExpression e = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new [] { x, y }, null, "(x + y) * 2");

var c = e.Compile();
var result = c.DynamicInvoke(1, 2);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```